# How disable file locks in Windows

Tags: windows, lock

How can I disable file locking in windows, so that locked files can be overwritten as in linux systems?

I am developing a plugin, which is a dll. Before compiling it again, i always need to unload it in the program, which loaded it. It would reduce the work a lot, if I could compile it always and just reload it later by unloading / loading again.
With linux this is no problem, the compiler just overrides the plugin and when it's opened the next time the new version will be used. Windows has a write lock on it, so the compiler cannot write it and aborts.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot "just" disable locking of executable/library files.

However, you can **move or rename** in-use files, so make your build process move the existing DLL elsewhere and compile the new one in its place.

---

It's very possible that they didn't add a hidden switch for it because various parts of the OS assume *it'll always be on*. For example, it could be that the filesystem code expects that there's always at least one link to a file (and therefore space can be freed immediately after deleting that last link) – so if you force it to delete an in-use file, it might result in various kinds of filesystem corruption, like two files using the same disk space.

That said, *The Old New Thing* has once written that it actually wouldn't be hard to allow Linux-style file deletion in the WinNT kernel, and that they just haven't done so to avoid some compatibility issues.